# Problems with inject in service

Tags: angular, jspm

I have a Angular2 application, where I created a service. Now I would like to extend the service to fetch some data from a web API. I have followed the developer guide from the angular team:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

read this fine guide about injecting a service:
http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html

But i keep getting the same error:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for 'UserService'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'UserService' is decorated with Injectable.

I have added both provides in the boostrap:

```
import "zone.js/dist/zone.min.js";
import "reflect-metadata";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS }    from 'angular2/http';
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { UserService } from '../userservice';
import { PublicappComponent } from './publicapp.component';

bootstrap(PublicappComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, UserService]);
```

And this is my simple UserService.ts:

```
import {Injectable}     from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable}     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Headers, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {UserModel}      from './usermodel';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(http: Http) { }
    private url = 'api/user';
}
```

I am using jspm around Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you include the `http.dev.js` file in your HTML entry file:

```
(...)
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.7/http.dev.js"></script>
```

**Edit**

Since Jspm allows to implement ES6-based Angular2 applications (not TypeScript), you can't use types of the level of method parameters. So you need to add a static getter for the `parameters` field:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private url = 'api/user';

  constructor(http) { }

  static get parameters() {
    return [[Http]];
  }
}
```

See this plunkr for more details: https://plnkr.co/edit/ymSUUCvG5NFvmCGqzj2r?p=preview

Comment: I am new to jspm, I should have the libs. Is there some way I can test this? If I try to log HTTP_PROVIDERS to the console I get the provider if I need the libs I should get undefined?

Comment: Okay. I think that it's because you only use ES6 not TypeScript... This way you can't use types within method parameters. I updated my answer...

Comment: I found the issue! It was because i somehow had an different and old path to TypeScript in Visual Studio 2015, even I had installed the newest from TypeScriptlang. So after correcting the TypeScript compiler version, I solved my problem! I found I could compile from commandline and not from VS. Thanks for the quick response!